# Cannot switch between 3 different backgrounds using Button in JavaFx for game dev project

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

I am trying to create a Scene in JavaFX for my high scores, which has 3 different methods which switch between the scores for Level 1, 2 and 3. When executing this code, the labels (which display the scores) overlap, and the buttons to switch between each display do not work. When I run the code, it switches between the output for Level1 and Level2, but then fails to go back and is stuck between switching to the output for displaying the high scores for Level 2 and 3.

```java
package sample;

import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import sun.plugin.javascript.navig.Anchor;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighScores {

    private ArrayList<String> levelOneNames = new ArrayList<>(0);
    private ArrayList<Integer> levelOneScores = new ArrayList<>(0);
    private ArrayList<String> levelTwoNames = new ArrayList<>(0);
    private ArrayList<Integer> levelTwoScores = new ArrayList<>(0);
    private ArrayList<String> levelThreeNames = new ArrayList<>(0);
    private ArrayList<Integer> levelThreeScores = new ArrayList<>(0);
    private AnchorPane layout;
    private String currentLevel = "1";
    private Label userName1, userScore1, userName2, userScore2, userName3, userScore3;

    private ArrowButton next, back;

    public Scene mainWindow ()
    {
        layout = new AnchorPane();
        readUserScores();
        sortList();


        next = new ArrowButton("right");
        next.setLayoutX(835);
        next.setLayoutY(350);
        layout.getChildren().add(next);

        back = new ArrowButton("left");
        back.setLayoutX(-35);
        back.setLayoutY(350);
        layout.getChildren().add(back);

        if (currentLevel.equals("1"))
        {
            next.setOnAction(event -> displayLevelTwoScores());
        }
        else if (currentLevel.equals("2")){
            next.setOnAction(event ->  displayLevelThreeScores());
            back.setOnAction(event -> displayLevelOneScores());
        }
        else
        {
            back.setOnAction(event -> displayLevelTwoScores());
        }

        displayLevelOneScores();

        return new Scene(layout, 1000, 750);
    }

    public void readUserScores()
    {
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("userscore_level1.txt"));
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                levelOneNames.add(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')));
                levelOneScores.add(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ')+1)));
               // arr.add(new Record(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')), Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1))));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("userscore_level2.txt"));
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                levelTwoNames.add(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')));
                levelTwoScores.add(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ')+1)));
                // arr.add(new Record(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')), Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1))));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("userscore_level3.txt"));
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = in.nextLine();
                levelThreeNames.add(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')));
                levelThreeScores.add(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ')+1)));
                // arr.add(new Record(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(' ')), Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(' ') + 1))));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Clears all the scores and names from the files.
     *
     * @since 1
     */
    public static void clearRecords() {
        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("userscore_level1.txt"));
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("userscore_level2.txt"));
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        try {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("userscore_level2.txt"));
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void sortList () {
        for (int x = 0; x<levelOneScores.size(); x++) {
            int temp = levelOneScores.get(x), pos = x;
            String tempName = levelOneNames.get(x);

            while (pos >0 && temp> levelOneScores.get(pos -1))
            {
                levelOneScores.set(pos, levelOneScores.get(pos -1));
                levelOneNames.set(pos, levelOneNames.get(pos -1));
                pos--;
            }
            levelOneScores.set(pos, temp);
            levelOneNames.set(pos, tempName);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x<levelTwoScores.size(); x++) {
            int temp = levelTwoScores.get(x), pos = x;
            String tempName = levelTwoNames.get(x);

            while (pos >0 && temp> levelTwoScores.get(pos -1))
            {
                levelTwoScores.set(pos, levelTwoScores.get(pos -1));
                levelTwoNames.set(pos, levelTwoNames.get(pos -1));
                pos--;
            }
            levelTwoScores.set(pos, temp);
            levelTwoNames.set(pos, tempName);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x<levelThreeScores.size(); x++) {
            int temp = levelThreeScores.get(x), pos = x;
            String tempName = levelThreeNames.get(x);

            while (pos >0 && temp> levelThreeScores.get(pos -1))
            {
                levelThreeScores.set(pos, levelThreeScores.get(pos -1));
                levelThreeNames.set(pos, levelThreeNames.get(pos -1));
                pos--;
            }
            levelThreeScores.set(pos, temp);
            levelThreeNames.set(pos, tempName);
        }

    }

    public void displayLevelOneScores()
    {
        layout.getChildren().removeAll(userScore2, userName2, userScore3, userName3);
        currentLevel = "1";
        int numOutput;
        BackgroundImage levelOne = new BackgroundImage(new Image("/Backgrounds/highscores_level1.png", 1000,
                750, false, true), BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);

        layout.setBackground(new Background(levelOne));

        if (levelOneScores.size()<=10)
            numOutput = levelOneScores.size();
        else
            numOutput = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i<numOutput; i++)
        {
            userName1 = new Label(levelOneNames.get(i));
            userName1.setLayoutX(130);
            userName1.setLayoutY(200 + i * 40);
            userName1.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", 24));
            layout.getChildren().add(userName1);

            userScore1 = new Label(String.valueOf(levelOneScores.get(i)));
            userScore1.setLayoutX(700);
            userScore1.setLayoutY(200 + i * 40);
            userScore1.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", 24));
            layout.getChildren().add(userScore1);

        }

    }

    public void displayLevelTwoScores()
    {
        layout.getChildren().removeAll(userName1, userScore1, userScore3, userName3);
        currentLevel = "2";
        int numOutput;
        BackgroundImage levelTwo = new BackgroundImage(new Image("/Backgrounds/highscores_level2.png", 1000,
                750, false, true), BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);

        layout.setBackground(new Background(levelTwo));

        if (levelTwoScores.size()<=10)
            numOutput = levelTwoScores.size();
        else
            numOutput = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i<numOutput; i++)
        {
            userName2 = new Label(levelTwoNames.get(i));
            userName2.setLayoutX(130);
            userName2.setLayoutY(200 + i * 40);
            userName2.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", 24));
            layout.getChildren().add(userName2);

            userScore2 = new Label(String.valueOf(levelTwoScores.get(i)));
            userScore2.setLayoutX(700);
            userScore2.setLayoutY(200 + i * 40);
            userScore2.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", 24));
            layout.getChildren().add(userScore2);

        }

    }

    public void displayLevelThreeScores()
    {
        layout.getChildren().removeAll(userScore2, userName2, userName1, userScore1);
        currentLevel = "3";
        int numOutput;
        BackgroundImage levelThree = new BackgroundImage(new Image("/Backgrounds/highscores_level3.png", 1000,
                750, false, true), BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
                BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);

        layout.setBackground(new Background(levelThree));

        if (levelThreeScores.size()<=10)
            numOutput = levelThreeScores.size();
        else
            numOutput = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i<numOutput; i++)
        {
            userName3 = new Label(levelThreeNames.get(i));
            userName3.setLayoutX(130);
            userName3.setLayoutY(200 + i * 40);
            userName3.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", 24));
            layout.getChildren().add(userName3);

            userScore3 = new Label(String.valueOf(levelThreeScores.get(i)));
            userScore3.setLayoutX(700);
            userScore3.setLayoutY(200 + i * 40);
            userScore3.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", 24));
            layout.getChildren().add(userScore3);

        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Not going through all your code, but this sounds like some resource is not released. The `Scanner`s may be candidates. They are never closed after you're done reading the file. try-with-resources is a good way of doing this. It's never a good idea to simply "swallow" errors. At least log them in some way. the easiest way is to simply print the stacktraces to `System.err`: `e.printStackTrace();` I also recommend avoiding code duplication: Introducing a method receiving a file name and 2 lists would reduce the code to about 40% in addition to making the logic simpler to rewrite.

Comment: You set the event handlers on the initial load. So the buttons action on level one loads level 2. But you never update the action to update the action. So clicking the button will always load level two scores (unless I missed something).  I would also suggest using more properties and allowing text fields to be bound. Something like currentLevelProperty then just switch the level data in and out based on a rotating counter.